# How do you calculate variable importance p-values using the randomForest package in R?

Tags: r, machine-learning, statistical-significance, p-value, random-forest

For a classification project we are using the randomForest package in R, which wraps the [Breiman](http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~breiman/RandomForests/cc_home.htm) Fortran random forest implementation, to assess the importance of each of our features. I would like to calculate p-values for each feature's *importance* statistics as described in the random forest documentation provided by [Breiman](http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~breiman/RandomForests/cc_home.htm#varimp).

> ... therefore we compute standard errors in the classical way, divide
>   the raw score by its standard error to get a z-score, ands assign a
>   significance level to the z-score assuming normality.

The R RandomForest package provides the *mean decrease importance* (MDI) metric for each of the classes and overall (both classes combined) in addition to the standard deviation for the *decrease importance* of each class and overall.

I don't understand how these values can be used to obtain a significance level for the variable importance as, while the mean and standard deviation will allow the construction of the a normal distribution, there is no "observation" for the z-score calculation. Can someone clarify how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

It is called z-score mainly because it is mean/sd, but in practice it is useless for hypothesis testing -- in some cases you can get most important attribute with z~$10^{-3}$ or on the other side all z-scores way larger than this mystical 3.

The working (more-less) approach is for instance to compare attributes' importance to an importance of random dummy attributes added to the set. I have made a package, [Boruta](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Boruta/index.html), that implements such idea.

Comment: Yes, I know what a z-score is and I understand how to calculate the significance based on permuted variable values, what I don't understand is how to do this from the information provided by the randomForest package in R: importance mean and importance standard deviation for each feature.

Comment: Well, you can't, that's the point. You must manually add this datum attributes, train the forest, get importance and do the test on original versus permuted.

Comment: There is no way to exploit the fact that the distribution given is the difference between the permuted and actual?

Comment: The problem is that this gives not enough power to do the test; the  attributes are not independent, the trees may also have some correlation, $N_\text{tree}\left<\text{depth}\right>/N_\text{attr}$ is not enough, etc. In short, it does not work.

Comment: What about a permuted measure of variable importance? I.e., re-run RFs with permuted class labels, say 1,000 times, and get the approximate $p$-values for the original importance measure?

Comment: chi, yes I could added a permuted feature for each feature in the analysis, in addition to what the randomForest routine is already doing; however I am trying to assess the importance of several hundred thousand (microarray) features so computational complexity because a factor.

Comment: What can I say... Microarray is an extreme case, thus requires extreme measures. One idea is to use few RF runs with many trees to first purge obviously irrelevant features (i.e. being consistently on the tail) and then use something to do proper test on the rest.

Comment: I have a subquestion which I'm not sure deserve a full SE question. Can you access the whole raw importance set of observations in order to compute the standard deviation yourself (I would like to use the whole distribution) ?